# Correctly convert decimal value to byte value

Tags: java

I need to convert decimal value like

```
int dec = 129;
```

into a byte value like

```
byte frame2 = (byte) 129;
```

but as you might already have guessed, it converts into an unexpected value. I want the byte value to be literally 129 instead of -127 (value of frame2).

How could you achieve it in Java? I would appreciate an explanation as well.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use byte: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html

Comment: @DekDekku That will be much slower, but how will it help? Can you demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: I just meant don't use byte. Nor Byte, which for the matter at stake is exactly the same thing.

Comment: @DekDekku Depending on OP's problem, if he needs to store values between 0 and 255, bytes may very well be suited. He just has to use it knowingly.

Comment: That's why I linked to the docs. His question shows that he doesn't know what byte is for (or not for).

Comment: @DekDekku I thought you were suggesting using Byte.  It's not clear what you were suggesting as an alternative.

Comment: @DekDekku As a matter of fact you weren't suggesting anything as an alternative at all. You just introduced the red herring of Byte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't and most likely you don't need to. a byte is -128 to 127 by definition.  However you can store any 256 different values in a byte if you want with encoding.

```
byte b = (byte) 129;
int i = b & 0xff; // == 129
```

or

```
byte b = (byte) (129 + Byte.MIN_VALUE);
int i = b - Byte.MIN_VALUE; // also 129.
```

Comment: +1 I'd say the byte is correct, it is both -127 or 129, that's more a problem of representation/use of the byte.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to convert decimal value like

Stop right there. There is no such thing as a 'decimal value'. There are values, which are held in 2s-complement, and there are decimal *representations.*

```
int dec = 129;
```

That will be stored as 129(10), or 81(16).

> into a byte value like

```
byte frame2 = (byte) 129;
```

The result of that will be `-127,` because bytes are signed in Java and your value sets the sign bit.

If you want to use the value as though it was `129`, use `(frame2 & 0xff).` However it is quite likely that you don't need to do that at all.

Your question is actually about sign-extension of bytes in Java: it has nothing to do with decimals at all.